# Wordpress Doesn't Like My Page Template Name

Tags: wordpress

Wondering if anyone has ever come across this problem. I've searched and searched and can't find a solution. It's probably staring me right in the face.

I've named a page template (page-exhibitions.php) and for some reason this page name does not display the content on it. It stops loading right after the header and picks back up on the footer, skipping over the entire template, but reading at least my get_header / get_footer.

No matter what else I name this page template, it works fine. I've check spelling until it's made me lose my mind. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to tell but I'd wager that you have some code (somewhere in your site, not necessarily in that file) that checks the [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) function for `page-exhibitions.php` which modifies [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check the files for that and see what I find. Incidentally, I changed the template name to "page-exhibition.php" (dropped the s) and as it started working with the name change another page template "page-collection.php" stopped displaying content... very strange. So, for the time being I have that page as "page-collections.php" and now they are both working. This is very strange.